# What to include in PyPi package?

Tags: python, packaging, pypi, pep

I'm packaging my new python library for **PyPi**. The repository contains:

- Sphinx documentation sources
- Supplemental JavaScript library
- Examples

Is it a good idea to include such things into a **python egg**?
What's the convention?

You can see the guts of the library at https://github.com/peterhudec/authomatic

Answer (score 2):

You shall not make everything into the python egg, but anyway, that's up to the `python setup.py bdist_egg` to choose what to include or not. But in the source package you upload to pypi, yes, include everything that can't be generated by setup.py. You can upload separately the documentation, so it can get published as well.

But generally, what you **need** to get included in the egg, is what is necessary for the egg to run as-is. Everything else can be included, but can be distributed through other ways, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There are packages on PyPI that are entirey (or almost) entirely written in bash (virtualenvwrapper.sh is one).

If there is a supplemental JavaScript library that you can package, that wouldn't be a bad thing. This prevents the case where the user might not have npm installed, so it makes your library easier to use and your users happier.

Documentation doesn't NEED to be included but if you want to, then by all means do it. Libraries both include and don't include documentation. [github3.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) now includes it while [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) does not. It's up to your preference.

I personally always have the examples in the documentation, so they're included in my packages that include the documentation. I can't think of any packages off the top of my head that include a separate package of examples, but if you feel it's necessary, then go ahead. I might, however, make that a sub-directory of the library itself though. It will make the name-spacing better when it is installed.

But basically, there are no set conventions beyond having the code to perform the task you say the package will perform.

Comment: Well, I didn't want this question to be considered a spam so I didn't include a link to the package, but now I see that it could make the answers more concrete. The package repository is hosted at https://github.com/peterhudec/authomatic

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell for PyQT4:

it includes doc, examples, plugins, ...

I do not know about your JavaScript library but I think it is no problem to include that as well.

This is an example - I do not know the convention. I would put in everything that could be important to the user of your library.